# Passing string as Thread start routine parameter : C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Referring to http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SCHEDULING

I am trying to create two threads in C++ and trying to pass the string as parameter to the `Thread Start Routine`. The `Thread Start Routine` parameter can only be `(void *)` type as per definition:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t * thread, 
                       const pthread_attr_t * attr,
                       void * (*start_routine)(void *), 
                       void *arg);
```

But I get below error:

```
$ make
g++ -g -Wall Trial.cpp -o Trial
Trial.cpp: In function `int main()':
Trial.cpp:22: error: cannot convert `message1' from type `std::string' to type `void*'
Trial.cpp:23: error: cannot convert `message2' from type `std::string' to type `void*'
Makefile:2: recipe for target `Trial' failed
make: *** [Trial] Error 1
```

The code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );


int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    string message1 = "Thread 1";
    string message2 = "Thread 2";

    int  iret1, iret2;


     iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
     iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);



     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join( thread2, NULL);



     cout << "Thread 1 returns: " <<  iret1 << endl;
     cout << "Thread 2 returns: " << iret2 << endl;


    return 0;
    }
void *print_message_function( void *ptr )

{
     cout << endl <<  ptr << endl;
     //return 0;

}
```

Is there any way to pass `string` as `(void *)` parameter ? Or Only `C style strings` can be used as Multithreading parameters - as given in the reference code at the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The argument needs to be a pointer, and you try to pass an object to it.

You have two choices, either pass a pointer to the `std::string` object, or pass a pointer to the underlying string. I recommend the first:

```
 iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, print_message_function, &message1);
```

Then you have to modify the thread function, as otherwise it will print the *pointer* and not the string it points to:

```
void* print_message_function(void* ptr)
{
    std::string str = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(ptr);

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return nullptr;
}
```

---

Unless it's a requirement to use POSIX threads, I would actually rather recommend the threading functionality in the [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void print_message_function(const std::string& msg);

int main()
{
    std::string message1 = "Thread 1";
    std::string message2 = "Thread 2";

    std::thread thread1(print_message_function, std::cref(message1));
    std::thread thread2(print_message_function, std::cref(message2));

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
}

void print_message_function(const std:string& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Using `iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, &message1);` I need to modify my `void *print_message_function( void *ptr )` as it shows the address of the string with present code.. How do I cast it to string?

Comment: Btw, be aware that you need to keep the 'message1' string to be valid during the whole life-cycle of the thread.

Comment: Is it safe to pass an argument located on the stack?

Comment: @Yossarian Since message1 is part of main thread , I think it is valid till the main thread is in execution .. and hence for thread1 as well .. right?

Comment: @Jiwan It depends, if it's on the stack of the `main` function it's generally safe. Otherwise I would say no. But it can be solved by using the [C++ thread functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) in the standard library.

Comment: @GauravK Updated my answer with a more... "C++'ish" version, using the C++ `thread` class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Does `string` create an object on stack ... or is it heap like `char *str= "Hello World";` in latter case it calls `new char[12]` to create the object on heap (including null character) .. if I am not wrong ?

Comment: @GauravK The string "inside" the string object is most likely on the heap, but the actual string _object_ is on the stack. And when declaring a _const_ string pointer (like `const char* str = "...";`) the string is not actually on the heap, but is in a read-only segment of the loaded executable.

Comment: Using the std::thread from the STL is definitely the way to go... if you are using a new enough compiler to support it. The OP may not be.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any arguments to the `pthread_create` method by wrapping all the arguments into simple structure. For example:

```
struct ThreadParams {
    std::vector<int> ints;
    std::string clientName;
    // more params
};
```

All you need to do is to initialize this structure before calling CreateThread function, and then pass a pointer:

```
ThreadParams * params = new ThreadParams();
params.setParameters();
pthread_create(..., params);

void* print_message_function(void* arg)
    ThreadParams * params = reinterpret_cast<ThreadParams *>(arg);
    // delete after usage;
    delete params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the address (memory location) of the string object when calling pthread_create:

```
iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*)&message1);
```

And you need to convert your memory void* back to a string pointer when you print it (you can't write a void* to a stream, the stream will not know what to do with it), the dereference it:

```
cout << endl <<  *(string*)ptr << endl;
```

This should work, but to be completely correct you should probably look at using reinterpret_cast when casting to and from void*.